# Trace GSM packets on HTC Desire?

Tags: htc-desire, resource-monitoring

Is there any way I can log/sniff the GSM packets on a (rooted) HTC Desire ?

(I'm talking about the actual low level GSM packets on the Um interface, not IP packets over a 3g connection.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [OpenBTS](http://openbts.sourceforge.net/). You'll need a Faraday cage and a couple thousand dollars in hardware, but you can control all interactions between the phone and your base station.

You will need a license to run a base station outside of a Faraday cage.

[Harald Welte's blog](http://laforge.gnumonks.org/weblog/) is a good one to follow if you're interested in GSM as a low-level protocol.

The "SMS of death" presentation at Chaos Computer Club one year used this sort of setup to test SMS buffer overflows.

Comment: But you can sniff GSM traffic without a Faraday cage.

Comment: Right, but if you want to **broadcast** GSM, you either want a license or a way to make sure it's only in a controlled environment. :)

Comment: true in most cases, but some of the GSM allocated spectrum is free-for-all in the US for low power broadcasts. No license needed.